# How to find a replacement globe for this style of lamp?

Tags: light-fixture, replacement

My oldest boy accidentally broke a lamp on the wall, and I'm stumped in googling for a replacement.

Is there a name for this style of lamp base, in which the globe simply rests in the base, not fixed in any way?

The base is three inches wide. This particular lamp was probably purchased in the early 70s.

[image]

Comment: Google any of these: 3” lamp chimney, 3” glass chimney, or hurricane chimney.

Comment: Whey you use comments to supply a fabulous answer like the one given above, the rest of us have no chance to weigh in and applaud. (After 40-years, I had no clue what that was called). Well done, Tyson.

Comment: @Tyson agreed.   Once I was exploring a turn of the century passenger car, and noting that not only were all the globes intact, *they matched*. I wondered how many hours and thousands of dollars they spent scouring every junkyard in America, so I asked.  They said they got them from a local supplier.   I asked which one: K-mart.  (It's like a Walmart.) **Globes and such things are standardized.**